# Vagrant halt doesn't work

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant

I am trying to shut down Vagrant with vagrant halt command, but getting this error:

(blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ vagrant halt The program 'vagrant' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install vagrant

Why?

Comment: What does `which vagrant` return? What OS are you on? How did you install vagrant? Did `vagrant up` work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

vagrant commands must be executed from the local machine. If you look at your bash prompt, you are still sshed (secure shelled) into your virtual machine. You need to exit the ssh session and then run the vagrant commands on your local machine in the local directory where your `Vagrantfile` configuration file is located.

You have SSHed into the vagrant machine.
first execute`exit` to get back to your machine and then execute`vagrant halt`